# How to make a Programm written in jdk12 on windows over intellij and compiled to .jar run in Linux with openJDK

Tags: java, linux

i have developed a small server, which works perfecctly in windows. i compiled this to a .jar file and pushed it to my linux server. I am unable to run the programm because of a version error. i found many informations on the internet but nothing solved my problem.

i developed it in windows with intellij using oracle jdk 12 and compiled it allready.
i have installed the default jdk (IcedTea 2.6.19) in my debian linux. i have also unzipped an openjdk 13 tar file but i dont know how and even if it is possible to execute this.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:

MultiThreadServer : Unsupported major.minor version 56.0

i would appriciate a solution. If i have to install an oracle jdk on my linux i would like to know how. i am new in windows and dont know how

Comment: Run it with the right version of Java on your Linux machine..

Comment: how do i install the right java version on debian? @xtratic

Comment: Here's a description of how to get and run a Java installer on Linux machines: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/09/install-oracle-java-13-on-ubuntu-linux.html

Comment: thank you very much it worked !

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to run your program against an inferior version of java.  You can check it by typing `java -version`

In order to make sure you are running the right java version for your program you may try:

- Use the full path of your JRE when launching the app.  Let's say (I am only guessing where you could have unzipped your OpenJDK 13):

`export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk/13 
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar whatever_my_app.jar`